# Get one table statistics (max, min, IQR, ...) for a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, iqr

I have a few data frames.

I need to display basic statistics together with  interquartile range (IQR) in one table for all of them.

Unfortunately, `summary` function does not return IQR.
On the other hand, [`fivenum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fivenum.html) returns IQR, but cannot (?) be applied on list of data frames and I don't need median.

Since I was unable to find appropriate function, I wrote one myself as follows:

```
removeXYcol <- function(df)
{
  # removes coordinates
  drops <- c("X","Y")
  withoutXY<- df[,!(names(df) %in% drops)]
  withoutXY
}

getStatsTable <- function(listOfDataFrames, df_names = NULL, digits_no = 2)
{
  # returns table with statistics (together with IQR which is not returned by summary)
  for (df in listOfDataFrames){
    df_data <- unlist(removeXYcol(df))

    minimum <- round(min(df_data,na.rm = TRUE),digits = digits_no)
    maximum <- round(max(df_data, na.rm = TRUE),digits = digits_no)
    average <- round(mean(df_data, na.rm = TRUE),digits = digits_no)
    IQR_ <- round(IQR(df_data, na.rm = TRUE),digits = digits_no)

    toReturn <- c(minimum, maximum, average, IQR_)
    if (exists("myStats")) {
      myStats <- rbind(myStats, toReturn)
    } else {
      myStats <- toReturn
    }

  }
  colnames(myStats) <- c("minimum", "maximum", "average", "IQR")
  if (is.null(df_names)) {
    df_names <- seq(length(listOfDataFrames))
  }
  rownames(myStats) <- df_names
  return(myStats)
}
```

However I wonder if there's no simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fivenum` takes a vector, so you've got to `lapply` across the list, plus `lapply` across the data.frame, e.g.

```
lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), function(df){lapply(df, fivenum)})

## [[1]]
## [[1]]$mpg
## [1] 10.40 15.35 19.20 22.80 33.90
## 
## [[1]]$cyl
## [1] 4 4 6 8 8
## ...
```

An alternative is `purrr::at_depth`, which allows you to specify the level of the list you want to iterate over:

```
purrr::at_depth(list(mtcars, mtcars), 2, fivenum)

## [[1]]
## [[1]]$mpg
## [1] 10.40 15.35 19.20 22.80 33.90
## 
## [[1]]$cyl
## [1] 4 4 6 8 8
## ...
```

A more involved version that returns a more nicely formatted list of data.frames:

```
library(tidyverse)

list(mtcars, mtcars) %>% 
    map(gather, var, val) %>% 
    map(group_by, var) %>% 
    map(summarise, 
        val = list(fivenum(val)), 
        label = list(c('min', 'q1', 'med', 'q3', 'max'))) %>% 
    map(unnest) %>% 
    map(spread, label, val)

## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 11 × 6
##      var     max     med    min       q1     q3
## *  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1     am   1.000   0.000  0.000   0.0000   1.00
## 2   carb   8.000   2.000  1.000   2.0000   4.00
## 3    cyl   8.000   6.000  4.000   4.0000   8.00
## ...
```

Comment: First version works for me, but this is not a nice table (it cannot be passed to xtable). I have problem with 'tidyverse' installation, but I believe that it works.